# Prove by induction that $n^5-5n^3+4n$ is divisible by 120 for all n starting from 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I've tried expanding $(n+1)^5-5(n+1)^3+4(n+1)$ but I end up with $120k+5(n^4+2n^3-n^2-2n)$ where k is any positive whole number, and I can't manipulate $5(n^4+2n^3-n^2-2n)$ to factor with 120.

Comment: Direct proof: $n^5-5n^3+4n=(n-2)(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)$.  $120=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5$.  Among the terms $n-2,n-1,\dots,n+2$ at least one of them will be divisible by five, at least one will be divisible by three, at least one divisible by four and at least one more other than the one divisible by four will also be divisible by two.

Comment: $n^4+2n^3-n^2-2n = (n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$. It's divisible by $24$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (you can prove this by induction as well, or simply prove it's divisible by $3$ and by $8$).

Comment: What do you mean k is any whole number?  This was for a specific value of n so it should have precisely one value in terms of n.  What do you get when you expanded it.

Comment: Prove the term in parenthesis us divisible by 24 via induction.  You'll get a term multipled by 4 you can prove is divisible by 6.  Proving that you get a term multiplied by 3 that you can prove is divisible by 2.  Proving that you get a term that that is clearly divisible by 1.  You can be perverse and do that.  But no-one will blame you if somewhere along the line you decide to simply factor and prove a result directly.  Still there's a cute little symmetry in recursive upon recursive induction.  Soothing and hypnotic in a way.

Comment: All these answers are good but they are all direct.  On the other hand induction is very inefficient and repetitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Show $\ 3,5,8\mid f(n)\! =\! (n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$

implies that $\ 3,5,8\mid\, f(n+1)\,\ =\,\ (n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$

Comment: Further hint: every sequence of $\,k\,$ consecutive integers contains a multiple of $\,k,\,$ and $\,5\mid n\!+\!3\iff 5\mid n\!-\!2\ $ by $\ n\!+\!3-(n\!-\!2) = 5\ \ $

Answer (score 8):

Using repeated differences and [Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series)  we get
$$
n^5-5n^3+4n = 120 \binom{n}{3} + 240 \binom{n}{4} + 120 \binom{n}{5} 
$$
Although this identity suffices for answering the question, it also implies the simpler identity below:
$$
n ^5-5n^3+4n = 120 \binom{n+2}{5}
$$
which gives a crystal clear answer to the question.

If you must use induction, then:
\begin{align}
f(n+1)-f(n)
&=5 n^4+10 n^3-5 n^2-10 n\\
&= 5 (n+2) (n+1) n  (n-1)\\
&= 5 (4!) \binom{n+2}{4}\\
&= 120 \binom{n+2}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain or link further explanation on how to write polynomials in the form you did? 
But basically what you did was to prove that every increment to the function was divisible by 120 which in combination with knowing that f(3) is divisible by 120 means that the whole thing is always divisible by 120?

Comment: @Ahmed, for the first expression, see the Wikipedia link I gave. The second expression follows directly from [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule). The last one is exactly what have understood; it depends on $f(3)$ being  divisible by $120$. ($f(n)$ for $n=0,1,2$ also works, because $f(n)=0$ in these cases.)

Answer (score 2):

Let it be true for k

$$k^3(k^2-1) - 4k(k^2-1) = k(k^2-4)(k^2-1) = (k+2)(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)$$ is divisible by 5,4,3,2 and hence 120

Now replace k by k+1

Then $$(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)k(k-1)$$ is still divisible by 5,4,3,2 and hence 120

It is true for any n>=3.

Comment: True.  And this is good (better than induction) but technically isn't induction as proving for k+1 in no way uses the property of k.

Answer (score 0):

${\binom{n+2}{5}= }$ ${\frac{(n+2)(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)} {5!} }$

- ${n^5-5n^3+4n = (n-2)(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)=  5!\binom{n+2}{5}}$