# How do you write a polynomial as a linear combination of binomial coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

So here [Prove by induction that $n^5-5n^3+4n$ is divisible by 120 for all n starting from 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851128/prove-by-induction-that-n5-5n34n-is-divisible-by-120-for-all-n-starting-fro) in a proof, the needed polynomial is written as a linear combination of binomial coefficients, and I just can't figure out how. If some of you could give me a step by step explanation on how do you exactly turn a polynomial into a form like that, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my explanation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1353749). Although it's for a different question, the technique is precisely what you want here. Basically you compute the forward differences of the first $6$ terms and then you can read off the coefficients for the Newton series.

Answer (score 3):

Note the powers $n^k$ can also be expressed with binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ by means of the so-called *[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* denoted with
$\begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}$.In the referred Wiki-page the relationship is given using falling powers
\begin{align*}
(n)_k=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)
\end{align*}
as
\begin{align*}
n^k=\sum_{j=0}^k\begin{Bmatrix}k\\j\end{Bmatrix}(n)_j\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Since binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{j}=\frac{(n)_j}{j!}$ we can write (1) as
>   \begin{align*}\
> n^k=\sum_{j=0}^k\begin{Bmatrix}k\\j\end{Bmatrix}\binom{n}{j}j!\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> In order to represent $n^5-5n^3+4n$ with binomial coefficients we calculate according to (2)
>
> \begin{align*}
> n^5&=\sum_{j=0}^5\begin{Bmatrix}5\\j\end{Bmatrix}\binom{n}{j}j!
> =1\binom{n}{1}1!+15\binom{n}{2}2!+25\binom{n}{3}3!+10\binom{n}{4}4!+\binom{n}{5}5!\\
> n^3&=\sum_{j=0}^3\begin{Bmatrix}3\\j\end{Bmatrix}\binom{n}{j}j!
> =1\binom{n}{1}1!+3\binom{n}{2}2!+1\binom{n}{3}3!\\
> n^1&=\sum_{j=0}^1\begin{Bmatrix}1\\j\end{Bmatrix}\binom{n}{j}j!
> =1\binom{n}{1}1!\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Putting all together gives
>   \begin{align*}
> n^5-5n^3+4n&=120\binom{n}{5}+240\binom{n}{4}+140\binom{n}{3}+30\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\\
> &\qquad-5\left(6\binom{n}{3}+6\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\right)\\
> &\qquad+4\binom{n}{1}\\
> &=120\left(\binom{n}{5}+2\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{3}\right)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Applying the induction step $n\rightarrow n+1$ to (3) it is obvious that the expression is a multiple of $120$.

Comment: The expression you tagged as $(2)$, has any specific name? What would be the best way to refer to it in a text? Binomial expansion for example?

Comment: @Peregring-lk: There is no specific name for this polynomial. It is not a binomial expansion, but it can be denoted as expansion of $k$-th powers of natural numbers in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind.